# Size container to smallest item height + max width

Tags: html, css, image

A container which contains images, the number of which can vary

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/400">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/500">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/500">
</div>
```

These images are of different heights. I want to size them such that **they're all the same height**, and they're the maximum width they can, be given the space available.

I have a feeling the answer involves flex-boxes, and `object-fit:`, but I can't quite piece it together.

Comment: This is going to be interesting, because you're not going to definitely know the size of the smallest image until all images have been loaded. Also, have you considered just using JavaScript?

Comment: It'd be preferable if it could be done with only CSS, but if it's only possible in JavaScript then it's only possible in JavasScript, and there isn't much to be done about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work and I've added comments to explain the logic.

```js
// Find all img elements in .container.
const images = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container img'));

// Add load event listener
images.forEach(image => image.addEventListener('load', imageLoad));

// Define initial minimum height
let minHeight = Infinity;
let imagesLoaded = 0;

// Image load event handler
function imageLoad(event) {
  // Recalculate minimum image height
  minHeight = Math.min(minHeight, event.target.height);
  imagesLoaded++;
  
  // Apply minimum height once all images are loaded
  if (images.length === imagesLoaded) {
    images.forEach(image => image.style.height = `${minHeight}px`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/500">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/300">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/500">
</div>
```

Comment: Using that and some table finagling, I was able to create something that does what I want here https://codepen.io/Azdaema/pen/ExxRwOR

Comment: Nice. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it, so that other people know yoir question is solved.